# Does python have super().__init__().area() this kind of method?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, superclass, python-class

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self,side):
        self.side = side
    
    def area(self):
        return self.side * self.side

class cube(Square):
    def area(self):
        return super().__init__().area() * 6
        
    def volume(self):
        return super().area() * self.side()
        
        
c = Square(4)
# print(c.area())
# print(c.volume())

d = cube(4)
print(d.area())
```

Can we actually use `super().__init__().area()` a method like this in python ?
If so then what does it mean ? The above code throws an error.

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'side'
```

Then can you please tell me what type of arguments we should use inside `__init__` and `super()` ?

Comment: `__init__` doesn't return anything (i.e. it returns None) so you can't call `.area()` on it. You have `super().area()` elsewhere in your code. What are you trying to achieve with `super().__init__().area()`?

Comment: You meant `return super().area() * 6`. But using inheritance here probably is more trouble than it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

`super().__init__().area() * 6`

Does not makes, as `__init__` must return `None` or as [`__init__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) say

> (...)no non-`None` value may be returned by `__init__()`; doing so will cause a
> `TypeError` to be raised at runtime.

and `None` has not `.area` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we actually use `super().__init__().area()` a method like this in python ? If so then what does it mean ?

It means nothing because it's complete nonsense: `super()` lets you access methods and attributes in a superclass context, so `super().__init__()` will call the superclass' `__init__` (outside of `__init__` which is a terrible idea), and that returns nothing, hence the failure.

> Then can you please tell me what type of arguments we should use inside `__init__` and `super()` ?

The question itself is wrong because all its assumptions are incorrect. If you want to call the superclass' `area` you just:

```
def area(self):
    return super().area()
```

though the inheritance relationship here makes no sense, there is no "IS A" relationship between a square and a cube, they're not substitutable for one another.